# unable to create angular6 project

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, angular6

I am trying create an angular6 project using the command "ng new project(project_name)" in integrated teminal of visual studio code. After creating few dependencies it is showing as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6m7u.png)/d : The term '/d' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ /d /s /c npm install --quiet
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/d:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Package install failed, see above.

Answer (score 0):

'ng new project(project_name)' - it's not like that your command should like - 'ng new project_name' EXAMPLE - ng new dreamapp.

in case if it doesn't work try this from scratch you will definitely solve this problem [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITWGFd2sosE)

Comment: Bro yes, I just specified 'Project' is the  name of the project  in the bracket.  Moreover it is working fine,  when I am creating project in windows command prompt,  the problem is when I am trying to create project using visual Studio code integrated terminal.